# ARC __block local variable not clearing

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

My understanding is that under ARC local variables should be cleared (set to 0).  However, I have a simple situation where when using a __block modifier the local variable isn't getting cleared.

Here is some a simple unit test that shows the problem.

```
- (void)testARCLocalVarClear
{
    FLPuzzleManager  *puzzleManager = [[FLPuzzleManager alloc] init];
    __block bool      loadDone;

    NSLog( @"value of loadDone = %d", loadDone );

    STAssertFalse( loadDone, @"ARC should have set loadDone to 0" );
}
```

I was trying to do this as part of a larger unit test that needed the __block variable.  I paired it down to this very simple example.

Should I expect ARC to clear the __block variable in this case?

[image]

Comment: Does ARC only pre-clear stack variables that are objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding is that ARC will automatically initialize stack local variables iff they are pointers to retainable objects **and** they have strong, weak, or autoreleasing qualification.

So all other locals, including primitives like what you have here, are going be uninitialized like always.